# Error 'Could not connect to TraCI server at localhost: 40335 [Errno 111] Connection refused'

Tags: flow-project

Repost from J. Guo:

Hi everyone,
I followed the document to install Flow and when type in 'python examples/sumo/sugiyama.py' to check my installation, it returned:
Could not connect to TraCI server at localhost: 40335 [Errno 111] Connection refused
Did anyone have the same error and what's the reason?

Best,

Jin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Repost from: Aboudy Kreidieh

One issue might be that you are not on the conda environment when you ran the simulation. Before you run an experiment from your terminal, type `source activate flow` and try again.

Let us now if this works!

Best,

Aboudy